# .Net - open excel workbook and it opens a previous version, cache

Tags: .net, vb.net, excel

If I open an excel workbook that's in my web app folder, when I read through the cells it give me values from a previous excel spreadsheet that I was working on. Could this be some cache issue?

```
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application = Nothing
    Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook = Nothing
    Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet = Nothing
    Dim misValue As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value
    Dim strCell2 As String = ""
    xlApp = New Excel.ApplicationClass
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("book1.xlsx")
    xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Worksheets("sheet1")
    Dim strOutput As String = ""
    Dim cell As Excel.Range
    Dim i As Integer = 1
    For Each cell In xlWorkSheet.Range("B:B")
        strCell2 = xlWorkSheet.Cells(i, 2).value
        If strCell2 <> Nothing Then
            strCell2 = xlWorkSheet.Cells(i, 2).value ' value here is of a different workbook
            i = i + 1
        Else
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
```

I can see the excel spreadsheet in my "Solution Explorer" and when I click on it it opens the correct workbook. Confused.com.

Any ideas, do I need to clear memory or cache before opening this?

Comment: Are you closing the excel application between calls? I'm not entirely sure but if Excel is already opened, it may return the already opened workbook when you call xlApp.Workbooks.Open().

Comment: Agree with Ceres - Excel automation does some odd things, so you should always shut it down when running .net apps using it. Also, try getting the full path of the file and calling that, rather than the short filename